# EJS Detect where include was called from

Tags: node.js, templates, express, ejs

I'm using EJS to include to maintain a standardized header and footer across a website.

```
<% include includes/footer %>
```

I'd like the footer to include file specific javascript for each page from which it is displayed:

```
<script src="public/js/<% NAME_OF_FILE_THAT_CALLS_FOOTER %>.js"></script>
```

Is this possible using node, express, and EJS?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to import js file in the each page, not in footer.

Page.ejs

```
<% include header %>
//body
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<% include footer %>
```

Footer.js

```
  // something more you want
  </body>
</html>
```